# Vector graphics in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, graphics, vector

I am new to Silverlight.  Just created my first application that shows deepzoom images.

Looking for some pointers how to display vector graphics in Silverligth.  The graphics are all in 2D and is a series of lines (x1y1, x2y2), points (xy), basic shapes.  The data is available in ASCII text files.

What is the way(s) to read the data from files and draw in SL?  Do I need to convert / translate the vector objects into images (XAML) first?  Where to start?

The ideal case is that all vector obects should be selectable either programmatically or by user actions.

Thanks,
Val

Comment: Include a small snippet of the ASCII text describing a reasonable simple item.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct drawing API to my knoweldge, but you can add the values seperately by adding various shapes to the visual tree.

The code you are looking for will likely involve the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path(v=VS.95).aspx) class and, in turn, [PathFigure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathfigure(v=VS.95).aspx) and [PolyLineSegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.polylinesegment(v=VS.95).aspx) (or possibly [LineSegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.linesegment(v=VS.95).aspx)).

Below is some code that draws a square:

```
PolyLineSegment segment = new PolyLineSegment();   
segment.Points.Add(new Point(0, 50));   
segment.Points.Add(new Point(50, 50));   
segment.Points.Add(new Point(50, 0));   
segment.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));   

PathFigure figure = new PathFigure()
{
    StartPoint = new Point(0, 0)
};
figure.Segments.Add(segment);

PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry()
{
    Figures.Add(pathFigure)
};

Path path = new Path()
{
    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    Data = pathGeometry
};

// To render, the Path needs to be added to the visual tree
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(path);
```

**Edit** If the data in the ASCII text files cannot change at runtime, it might be worth investigating writing a script that transforms the files into XAML so it can be compiled.

Comment: Thanks Richard.

The data will not be changed at runtime, so I will look into XAML compiling.

Have a nice weekend,
Val

Answer (score 0):

First of you have the issue of actually getting access to the files.

**Getting the file content**

If you have these files held somewhere serverside then you would use `WebClient` to fetch the file using `DownloadStringAsync`.

On the other hand if the user is to open a file locally then you need use the `OpenFileDialog` class to ask them to open the file and then use `OpenText` on the `FileInfo` object that `OpenFileDialog` provides to read the string data.

**Parsing**

Well its your format so you'll have to code that yourself.

__Generating UI elements_

You will not have to convert it to Xaml.  Since you want these vector items to be individually selectable elements then you probably want to use the set of `Shape` types found in the `System.Windows.Shapes` namely, `Elipse`, `Line`, `Path`, `Polygon`, `Polyline` and `Rectangle`.

No doubt the format in question has someway to define the position of these elements relative to a fixed 0,0 point.  Hence the best panel to use to display these is a `Canvas`.

You would read through each Vectored item, select create an instance of one of the appropriate shapes set its properties based on the data in the item.  You would need to determine its correct location within a `Canvas` and use the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties.  The add the shape to the `Children` collection of the `Canvas`.

Comment: Got it.  I will try that on the weekend.  Thanks for a prompt reply.

Cheers,
Val